# How to redirect a user to another page within the CMS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am developing a content management system (CMS). I did this with php, but now I want to add jquery because I don't want page reload when a form is submitted. I can submit a form using jquery. What I want now is after form is submitted to take the user to a different page (desired_page.php) within the CMS, replacing the page that contains the form. I can do this with php using window.open('index.php?desired_page','_self'), but I don't know how to do this with jquery. window.location.replace("desired_page.php") actually redirected me to desired_page.php, but outside the CMS. How can I replace the form with desired_page.php after form is submitted? My codes are shown below:

**HTML**

```
<form action="set_date_form.php" id="setdate" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="date" id="datetimepicker" placeholder="Choose Date" class="form-control" maxlength="2" required/>
<button id="subdate"class="btn btn-default" ><b>Set Date</b></button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('body').on('click', '#subdate', function(){
    $.post($("#setdate").attr("action"), $("#setdate").serialize(), function(info){ $("#resultm").html(info); } );
    clearInput();
    pageRedirect();
});

$('body').on('submit', '#setdate', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
function pageRedirect() {
    window.location.replace("sent_messages.php");
}
setTimeout("pageRedirect()", 10000);
function clearInput() {
  $("#setdate")[0].reset(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the form with desired_page.php
Use [Jquery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for replacing the content inside the form.

Comment: Do you mean something like this $('#lik1').hide();

Comment: Try to load the content of the page inside a div and then replacing the div content with load function. $('#div_id').load("sent_messages.php");

Comment: I put the whole form inside a div with an id 'formID' . I then did this: $('#formID').load('sent_messages.php'). The form disappears but sent_messages.php does not appear.

Comment: Please use full url in that.

Comment: I fixed it. On the php page that submits the data to database, after sending to the database I added: if($insert_query){
include("sent_messages.php");} Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

While using window.location.replace 
You need to specifies the FULL URL of the page to navigate to it.

for eg: window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/sent_messages.php");

Comment: I am still on my local saver. Should I use ("http://www") on my localhost?